# Which conditions need to be fulfilled for a FODO cell to provide focusing in both planes?

Tags: magnetic-fields, accelerator-physics

I often come across the claim that a FODO cell can provide focusing in both planes so long as said cells are appropriately configured.  I have *never* come across any elaboration of what this "appropriate configuration" actually is.

It is apparent to me that a FODO cell can be net defocusing, focusing or neither.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this claim?

Answer (score 1):

In thin lens approximation, the focal length $f$ of the magnets in the cell, needs to satisfy the condition:

$$f \geq \frac{L}{4}$$

where $L$ is the length of the whole periodic cell.

If the focal length is decreased too much (meaning that the focussing magnets are made stronger) a waist is created between the magnets and a periodic solution doesn't exist any longer.

The above relation follows from the expression of the cell phase advance $\mu$:

$$ \left| \sin \frac{\mu}{2} \right| = \frac{L}{4f}$$

which is derived computing the trace of the cell's transport matrix. Any good textbook of accelerator physics will help you with this.